# How do you show milliseconds on the time on vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, clock, system-clock

I have a clock on VB and i have got it to say the date and time but it wont show the milliseconds on the time.

```
time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss")
```

So I know how to put the hours minuets and seconds but im not sure how to add milliseconds.

Please could someone help.
Thank You

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: I agree that for such a question, searching the web is a better idea, but there is no reason to downvote this question. The user has asked a question that fills all the criteria of a good question. Statement of problem. Included code. Included expected behaviour and desired behaviour. Just because the question is pretty basic is not a reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `fff` to represent the milliseconds.

For example:

```
time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the possible placeholders.

Comment: Good solution, this will include any trailing 0's from milliseconds, if OP doesn't want trailing 0's `FFF` can be used.